# Search through a large file

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, full-text-search

Suppose you have a text file of size around 20GB which contains multiple lines,
you need to put this file at server and create a rest api which which take content as request param and you need to send all lines in response which matches given content.

you have limited space (lets say 256 MB) on server so you cant keep that file in memory.

Comment: return lines that partially match the given content or exactly match?

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: return lines that exactly match with the given content

Answer (score 0):

In .Net StreamReader.ReadLine is used for reading large files one line at a time. You can build up your reponse after each read

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: Right but that is naive approach
In this case you need to read the complete file for each request.
So if N requests comes up at server you will be reading complete file N times